# Dynamic Web Project option missing in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-kepler

The "Dynamic Web Project" option for a new project in Eclipse does not showing up in the list. 
Although the "web" folder showing up  with option "static web project" but there is no option for "Dynamic Web project".
I have already installed Web, XML, Java EE plugin. 
I am using Eclipse Kepler realease-2.

Answer (score 49):

I had the same problem and did this:

1. Click "Help" > "Install new software"
2. In "Work with", paste: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
3. In "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development", check:

   1. Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
   2. Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
   3. Eclipse Web Developer Tools
   4. Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

Finally, click "Next" to install the new software and "Dynamic Web Project" will be available.

Comment: Installed all four with success. But still no luck with the "Dynamic Web Project". Still Unavailable. On Eclipse Mars.1 Release 4.5.1

Comment: I've tried this solution but it was not enough. For me, what worked was the instruction given by Ankit: In Market Place, search for 'Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools'" and selected all the plugins listed above. Worked for Eclipse Orion Version.

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Eclipse they no longer have project names. For me I had to add the following URL: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/ (my version is 2021-12). You can find your version by clicking `Help -> About Eclipse`.

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1:** Click on Help and then click on “Install New Software”.

**Step 2:** In "Work with", paste this link: Mars- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars

**Step 3:** Scroll down to find “Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development” option and expand it.

**Step 4:** Select the following three options under “Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development”

- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
- Eclipse Web Developer Tools

**Step 5:** Click next and you should see that the software is installing. Wait for some time and then a popup would ask your permission to restart the Eclipse. Restart it and you should find the dynamic web project option under project list.

Answer (score 4):

Switch from java to java EE tab at top right of eclipse editor and then look New->Dynamic Web Project

Answer (score 2):

```
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
Eclipse Web Developer Tools
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
```

These need to be installed.

Now if in your new project you don't get Dynamic Web Project, select a new Project. In that you can go to Web-> Dynamic Web Project.

I don't know when this started, but in Mars.2 I found it here.

Comment: worked for me. I searched  for 'Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools' in eclipse market place and selected all the plugins listed above. I am using eclipse luna.

Comment: Does this same for eclipse neon?

Comment: Why don't you try it... I'm sure it must be the same since oxygen works similarly

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded the 4 files in Eclipse Kepler 4.3, and options for both Dynamic and Static Web project are now available. Can also create HTML5, JS, CSS files for a Hybrid Android application.

Answer (score 1):

We can locate the Create Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse at top Menu bar button, hover mouse pointer over each one of them to find out

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on Help and then click on “Install New Software”.
2. In Work with paste this link: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/Kepler
   Change the link according to your Eclipse version, for example for the Eclipse 
   2020-03 the link would be http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03
3. Scroll down to find “Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development” 
   option and expand it.

   4.Select the following three options under “Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development”

   -Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

   -Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools

   -Eclipse Web Developer Tools
4. Click next and you would see that the software are installing. Wait for some time and then a popup would ask your permission to restart the Eclipse. Restart it and you would find the dynamic web project option under project list.

Answer (score 0):

Which "Java EE" plug-in do you mean? That wizard requires that the `Java EE Developer Tools` feature be installed, and you be running with at least Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

actually, you just need to check the check box for generating the web xml, see here
[Eclipse Kepler not generating web.xml automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019934/eclipse-kepler-not-generating-web-xml-automatically)

Answer (score -1):

install plugin in eclipse for web application. Then dynamic web application option will come.
Find plugin link from here 
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started#creating 
And go to help->Install new software-> paste link in work with and click on add select all available plugin.

It could hep you.